# Getting error in android device "requiring unknown module 873", working fine in emulator

Tags: react-native

I am trying to execute a react-native project on an Android device, but for some reasons it is not working for me.

Please find below the dependencies which have been used in the project:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-secure-key-store": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-svg": "6.5.3",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-tabbar-bottom": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Note: this is working fine on emulator. I am trying to avoid use of emulator because it is too slow to use.

Comment: did you try to delete the build folder and clean cache?

Comment: Yes I have tried by deleting **android build** and **node-module** folder but couldn't fix.